# Why sscanf can't read an uint64_t and a char from one string?

Tags: c++, char, cstdio, cstdint

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::uint64_t ui;
    char c;
    auto ret = std::sscanf("111K", "%lu64%[B, K, M, G]", &ui, &c);

    assert(ret == 2);
    assert(ui == 111);
}
```

I tried to use `sscanf` to read a `uint64_t` and a `char` from one string, but it only read it `ui` (assertion `ret == 2` fails) every time I tried this.

Comment: 'K' is, but should be `[BKMG]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues here.  First

```
%lu64
```

should be

```
"%" SCNu64
```

to read in a 64 bit integer.

The second issue is

```
%[B, K, M, G]
```

requires a `char*` or `wchar_t*` as its output parameter as it populates a c-string.  You need to change

```
char c;
```

to at least

```
char c[2] // 2 because it adds a null terminator
```

in order capture `K`.  We put that all together and we get

```
auto ret = std::sscanf("111K", "%" SCNu64 "%[B, K, M, G]", &ui, c);
```

---

Do note that

```
%[B, K, M, G]
```

is actually trying to match all of the spaces and comma inside the brackets.  You could also write it as

```
%[BKMG]
```

and get the same results.

Answer (score 3):

Your format string expects characters `64` to follow the integer. `%lu` is the format specifier; `64` are literal characters.

Comment: The missing piece is the `SCNu64` macro

Answer (score 3):

Your format string is invalid.
It should go like this on 64 bit builds: `"%lu%1[BKMG]"` and `"%llu%1[BKMG]"` when building for 32 bits.

The universal solution uses `SCNu64` macro: `"%" SCNu64 "%1[BKMG]"`. This macro is defined in `cinttypes` header file.

Also your last parameter is passed incorrectly. It have to be an array of characters since zero will be appended at the end. Your code leads to undefined behavior since when `c` value will be written, something beyond this variable also will be written.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::uint64_t ui;
    char s[32];
    auto ret = std::sscanf("111K", "%lu%1[BKMG]", &ui, s);

    std::cout << "ret=" << ret << "  ui=" << ui << " s=" << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/17vZ8OkydJ7zQmP4
https://wandbox.org/permlink/z21Rbsu4mAseZyS4

Comment: It's just interesting that in case of `char s[1]` (or using a single `char` instead as in the question), `sscanf` might rewrite the lsb of `ui` with trailing zero on the stack. Which then silently results in `ui` having zero value. Of course, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: this is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: Sure, this is what I wrote. Someone just might wonder that it can result in `c` having value `'K'` and `ui` having value 0 instead of 111.